# split up a file with regex in python

Tags: python, regex

It is loads of questions that are almost the same as mine, but i still cant get it to work. I want to read a file and get the relevant information. I am trying to do it with regex in python.

copy of file:

```
       File name    : tmp2.jpg
       File size    : 179544 bytes
       File date    : 2003:03:29 10:58:40
       Camera make  : Canon
       Camera model : Canon DIGITAL IXUS 300
       Date/Time    : 2002:05:19 18:10:03
       Resolution   : 1200 x 1600
       Flash used   : Yes
       Focal length : 11.4mm  (35mm equivalent: 79mm)
       CCD width    : 5.23mm
       Exposure time: 0.017 s  (1/60)
       Aperture     : f/4.0
       Focus dist.  : 1.17m
       Exposure bias:-0.33
       Metering Mode: matrix
       Jpeg process : Baseline
```

What I am trying:

```
  infile = sys.argv[1]
  ifile = open(infile, 'r').read()

  myInfo = re.split('\s*\n:', ifile)

  for x in range(len(myInfo)):

       if myInfo[x] == 'Date/Time':
            print x
            x = x + 1
```

What it needs to do:

I need to get this information: 2002:05:19 18:10:03
from this line: Date/Time    : 2002:05:19 18:10:03

Why cant i just split on : and space and newline?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regular expression. Use [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [`str.strip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).

```
>>> 'Date/Time    : 2002:05:19 18:10:03'.split(':', 1)
['Date/Time    ', ' 2002:05:19 18:10:03']
>>> name, value = map(str.strip, 'Date/Time    : 2002:05:19 18:10:03'.split(':', 1))
>>> name
'Date/Time'
>>> value
'2002:05:19 18:10:03'
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the help! But its still a problem. I need to write a script that works with different files. The files are built up in the same manner as the file i presented a copy of. But the numbers are different. Your solution only work on this example. Any thoughts?

Comment: @user2160022, Which numbers are different? Could you post the content of the another file?

Comment: It is solved now, but still: 2002:05:19 18:10:03 this information changes eg: 2012:01:29 12:12:04. See the problem i had?

Comment: @user2160022, save the value of `value` to another variable if you find match. Or, it will be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer not to use `read()`. You don't need all the data in your program at one time. Just iterate over each line of the file.

```
import io
data = """       File name    : tmp2.jpg
       File size    : 179544 bytes
       File date    : 2003:03:29 10:58:40
       Camera make  : Canon
       Camera model : Canon DIGITAL IXUS 300
       Date/Time    : 2002:05:19 18:10:03
       Resolution   : 1200 x 1600
       Flash used   : Yes
       Focal length : 11.4mm  (35mm equivalent: 79mm)
       CCD width    : 5.23mm
       Exposure time: 0.017 s  (1/60)
       Aperture     : f/4.0
       Focus dist.  : 1.17m
       Exposure bias:-0.33
       Metering Mode: matrix
       Jpeg process : Baseline"""

for line in io.StringIO(data):
    if line.strip().startswith('Date/Time'):
        datetime = line.split(':', 1)[1].strip()
print(datetime)
```